# Is bunch countable? Can you have "bunches" of something?

Tags: grammaticality, countable-nouns

I was just looking up a recipe and this is what I saw:

> 2 large bunches of spinach, about 1 lb

I'm confused. Since bunch means lot of something, I've never seen someone counting it. After all, technically 2 bunches of something is still bunch all together, isn't it?

Is the recipe wrong, or do I have something to learn today?

Comment: I have a bunch of apples.  You have a bunch of oranges.  Together we have a couple of bunches of fruit.

Comment: A *bunch* of broccoli, also called a *stalk* or a *head*, is countable. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+stalk+of+broccoli%2C+a+head+of+broccoli%2C+a+bunch+of+broccoli&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20stalk%20of%20broccoli%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20head%20of%20broccoli%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20bunch%20of%20broccoli%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: As long as they are distinguishable from one another (often by string or rubber band when referring to produce)

Comment: Recipes can be very ambiguous in situations like this.  Here in the UK, spinach often comes in plastic bags of various sizes, so a "bunch" is fairly meaningless.  Since you have the alternative measurement (1lb), just use that.

Comment: Nouns have different usages. 'Two bunches of carrots' is fine (though of indeterminate weight); 'I have a whole bunch of stuff to do before I can come out.' is a non-count usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spinach is often sold in bundles tied with wire or twine or rubber bands.  Those bundles are referred to as "bunches".  Since a bundle of spinach could be variable in size, the recipe provides additional information.  If you went to your store and discovered a single bundle or bunch of spinach weighed one pound, you would need to buy only one.  Spinach, radishes, parsley and similar vegetables are sold this way.

Comment: If you are buying loose items and need an equivalent (and the recipe doesn't provide additional info), a bunch is generally the largest amount you can fit into one hand.

Comment: So basically it's completelly different word? Basically noun that means vegetables bundled with twine? Can this be used for other things, like bunch of sticks, or bunch of herbs (eg. when drying them?)

Comment: Specifically, could I use it in sentence "There were several bunches of herbs hanging from the ceiling."?

Comment: Yes.  "There was a bunch of parsley and 3 bunches of sage".  Sticks would generally be 'bundle', not bunch.  Also look up the verb form - "The fabric of the shirt was all bunched up".

Comment: @TomášZato 'Bunch can be used for all sorts of things that are tied in a bundle. Generally the things are narrow and often soft as plant stems often are. The hairstyle that is commonly called 'pigtails' in the US is called 'bunches' in Britain. In my experience 'bunch' in the 'bunch of stuff' sense is a much more recent usage.

Comment: Looks like no one yet mentioned "a bunch of grapes", also perfectly countable, and it's not something 'bundled with a twine'.